# Javascript arrays as objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Length of Javascript Object (ie. Associative Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array)
>   [Loop through JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

```
var location = {
     "Steve": "New York",
     "Abigayle": "Chicago"
}

for (var i = 0; i < location .length; i++)
{
    console.log('works');
}
```

I'm trying to make an array, where each item has some name and value.

The code above doesn't work. Tryed to make an object, but it doesn't have a `length` property - no `for` loop.

```
location= {
     "Steve": "New York",
     "Abigayle": "Chicago"
};
```

Is it possible to use arrays in this context?

Comment: @H2CO3 this question not about `.size()`

Comment: Using "Steve" as key is only a good idea until a second Steve enters the room...

Comment: @Christophe there is just one Steve in the context, so no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, you can iterate over all the keys in an object:

```
location = {
     "Steve": "New York",
     "Abigayle": "Chicago"
};

for (var elem in location) {
    console.log(elem);
}
```

Produces:

```
Steve
Abigayle
```

But I think that one of the other answers is probably the correct way to what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks good. I would like to operate with `name` and `value` inside loop, not just a `value`. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, then you just need to do the lookup `location[elem]`. However, like I said, I don't think this is the way you should be doing this, in case you have duplicate names, etc.

Comment: A word of warning, there is no guaranteed sort order when looping an object like this so you may find edge cases that don't behave as expected.

Comment: Dublicate names is not an issue for the context where it will be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to work with what you have,

```
var location = {
     "Steve" : "New York",
     "Abigayle" : "Chicago"
}

for (var name in location) {
    console.log( name, location[name] );
}
```

If you care about the length, use an Array of objects

```
var location = [
     { key : "Steve", value : "New York" },
     { key : "Abigayle", value : "Chicago" }
];
```

But there is no easy way to look it up, it would require a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var locations = [
     ["Steve","New York"]
    ,["Abigayle","Chicago"]
];
```

or

```
var locations = [
      {Name:"Steve",Location:"New York"}
     ,{Name:"Abigayle",Location:"Chicago"}
];
```

you could output the data in the 1st option like this:

```
var delimiter = "    ";
console.log("var locations = [");
for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
{
    var innerdelimiter = "";
    var line = delimiter + "[";   
    for (var j=0; j<locations[i].length;j++)
    {
       line += innerdelimter + locations[i][j];
       innerdelimiter = ",";
    }
    line += "]";
    console.log(line);
    delimiter = "   ,";
}
console.log("];");
```

and data in the 2nd option like this:

```
var delimiter = "    ";
console.log("var locations = [");
for (var key in locations)
{
    console.log(delimiter + "{" + key + ":" + locations[key] + "}");
    delimiter = "   ,";
}
console.log("];");
```

Comment: what about `for`, how do I get `new york` from `steve`?

Comment: Now that I've given you something that actually compiles, why don't you play with it a bit?

Comment: for the first var, seems I have to use [0] or [1], for the second its `.name` and `.location`. Maybe you know a better way to handle data inside loop.

Comment: second var looks too complicated, I have to make many dublicates of the object item names. It doubles an array size.

Comment: So tempted to turn this into a [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), but I haven't the time right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can `loop` over *object keys* aswell. Only if you require *indexed* keys you should use an *Array* here.

```
var loc = {
     "Steve": "New York",
     "Abigayle": "Chicago"
};

Object.keys( loc ).forEach(function( name ) {
    console.log('name: ', name, ' city: ', loc[ name ] );
});
```

By the way, `location` is a (pretty much) reserved variable name within the `window` object. You can't really overwrite that, so you should re-name that variable.

---

<sup>The above code uses Ecmascript 262 edition 5 code which works in all modern browsers. If you want to support legacy browsers you need to load any of the various ES5 shim libraries</sup>

Comment: Nice turn, but `forEach` doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: @Steve: Yes as I mentioned. It works like everywhere natively nowadays tho. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Steve: I wouldn't crash the party because of one browser (especially, not THAT browser). As I also mentioned, there a tons of great, very neat and small, shim libs which fix those legacy things.